# Do we have $\nu_t (t!) = o(t)$?

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

For any positive integer $t>1$, we can define $\nu_t(n)$ as the maximal integer $k$ such that $t^k\mid n$. (Here we don't need $t$ to be a prime.)

Then I wonder if we have
$$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\nu_t(t!)}{t}=0$$

For the most naive bound, I only have
$$\nu_t(t!)\leq \log_t (t!)\sim t$$
So it must use Legendre's theorem to delete some useless prime in $t!$. But I still cannot prove this limit...

Comment: A less naive estimate: $\nu_p(t!)$ is like $\frac{t}{p}$ and $\nu_{p^n}(t!)$ is like $\frac{t}{np}$, so for $\nu_t(t!)/t>\varepsilon>0$ we need to bound the size of $p$ and the power of $p$ which appears in $t$.  But there are only finitely many of those.

Comment: Actually $\nu_t(t!)$ equals to the $[\frac{\nu_p(t!)}{\nu_p(t)}] \leq\frac{t}{p-1}\cdot\frac{1}{\nu_p(t)}$ among all prime $p~|~t$. But I don't know how to use this?

Comment: $\nu_t(t!)$ is the minimum over all primes $p\mid t$ of that, so for $\nu_t(t!)/t>\varepsilon$ we must have $\frac1{\nu_p(t)(p-1)}>\varepsilon$ (eqn) for every $p\mid t$ and you know there are only finitely many $(p,\nu_p(t))$ pairs satisfying (eqn), hence finitely many $t$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \frac{\nu_t(t!)}{t} \leqslant \frac{\nu_p(t!)}{\nu_p(t) \cdot t} \leqslant \frac{t}{(p-1)\nu_p(t)\cdot t} = \frac{1}{(p-1)\nu_p(t)} $$

for any prime $p$ (where first inequality follows from the fact that $t^{\nu_t(t!)} \mid t!$, and the second one is consequence of [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula). Suppose $\frac{\nu_t(t!)}{t}$ will stay above some $c>0$ infinitely many times, so our sequence won't be convergent to zero. Then, for all $p \mid t$, $c \leqslant \frac{1}{p-1}$, so $p \leqslant c^{-1}+1$ and all prime divisors of $t$ are bounded. Similarly, for all $p \mid t$ we have $\nu_p(t) \leqslant c^{-1}$. But this gives bound on $t$: it can't be larger than product of all primes less than $c^{-1}+1$, raised to power $c^{-1}$. This is a contradiction with assumption about our sequence not being convergent to zero; thus

$$ \lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{\nu_t(t!)}{t} = 0 $$

as we wanted to prove.